# readFragment to return all object of a type

Tags: apollo-client

i'm using Apollo Client do request a very structured dataset from my server. Something like

-**Show**
id
title
...
-**Seasons**
 number
 -**Episodes**
  id
  number
  airdate

Thanks to normalization my episodes are stored individually but i cannot query them. For exemple i would like to query all the episodes to then sort them by date to display coming next.

the only way i see is to either 'reduce' my show list to an array of episode and then do the filtering. Or to do a new query to the server. 
But it will be so much faster if I could get a list of all Episodes in cache.
Unfortunately with readFragment you can only query One object by its id.

**Question:**
Is there a way to query the cache for all object of a defined type?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is late, but could have helped someone else, currently apollo does not support it. This is the issue here from github, and also a work around.
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/4724#issuecomment-487373566

Here is the copied workaround by @superandrew213

```
const serializedState = client.cache.extract()

const typeNameItems = Object.values(serializedState)
.filter(item => item.__typename === 'TypeName')
.map(item => client.readFragment({
  fragmentName: 'FragmentName',
  fragment: Fragment,
  id: item.id,
}))
```

Please take note that this method is slow, especially if you have a large normalized data.